# Не работает скрипт на питоне

Tags: python-3.x

Подскажите, есть скрипт на питоне, который должен выполнять партиционирование БД MySQL на сервере с Ubuntu 20.4
есть две версии,одна старая со старого сервера БД MariaDB и новая на сервере с MySQL
https://cloud.mail.ru/public/55Qb/GqCdzDEGS

Версия которая zabbix_partitioning.py выдает ошибку при запуске на новом сервере

```
File "zabbix_partitioning.py", line 59
    except mysql.connector.ProgrammingError, err:
```

Новая версия zabbix_partitioning_p3.py при запуске на новом сервере выдает

```
File "zabbix_partitioning_p3.py", line 1034, in <module>
    if db.connect() is False:
  File "zabbix_partitioning_p3.py", line 62, in connect
    self.cnx = pymysql.connect(user=self.db_user,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pymysql/__init__.py", line 94, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ssl_verify_cert'
```

Что не так? На старом сервере zabbix_partitioning.py работает.

Comment: в ошибке прямо написано что не так: "__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ssl_verify_cert'"

Comment: Не устанавливается подключение с СУБД.

Comment: Это где надо изменить? В скрипте убрать строку ssl_verify_cert = self.db_ssl.get('ssl_verify_cert', False), ?